# How can I update TableView in ScalaFX?

Tags: scala, javafx, scalafx

I have a table view. When I update the properties of one row, I can not see the modifications? For example:

```
implicit class PersonView(p:Person) {
  val fname = new ObjectProperty(this, "fname",p.name)
}
```

and in my table view

```
lazy val tableLines = ObservableBuffer(persView)
val personTable = new TableView[PersonView](tableLines) {
  columns ++= List(
    new TableColumn[PersonView, String] {
      text = "Name"
      cellValueFactory = _.value.fname
      cellFactory = { _ =>
        new TableCell[PersonView, String] {
          item.onChange { (_, _, newValue) => text = newValue }
        }
      }
    }
  )
}
```

It works fine, but when I update the name, I can not see that in GUI.

Comment: I don't speak Scala, but it looks like you have two classes here: `Person` and `PersonView`, with `Person` having a name field that is a plain `String` (i.e. not an observable JavaFX property of any kind). Are you updating the `Person` instance, or the `PersonView` instance? If my understanding is correct, and you are updating the `Person` instance, there is simply no way for the table view to "know" about that change.

Comment: in fact the `PersonView` is a Simplified model  adapted to ScalaFx TableView i'm updating `Person` and then i'm doing  `array.toBuffer[Person].map(new PersonView(_))` so the tabelview see the  changes no ?! anyway thank you for your answer.

Comment: I don't think that works: surely `array.toBuffer[Person].map(new PersonView(_))` just creates a collection of **new** `PersonView` instances: it doesn't update the existing ones. The table is observing the instance you created previously, whose properties haven't changed. You need to arrange to update the properties of your existing collection of `PersonView` instances.

Comment: yes i see but i thought `item.onChange` do the trick but if you have an example i will glad  thank you

Comment: Thank you Mike Allen and james_D i solved the problem ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, I'll attempt to summarize what I'm seeing, and how I think you might get this to work:

The `PersonView` class decorates a `Person` instance by providing an `fname` property, that is initialized to the `name` field of the associated `Person`. When creating each cell in the "Name" column, you create such a property and associate it with the value of the cell. Henceforth, whenever the value of that property changes, the cell will automatically change its `item` field to show the new value of that property. (BTW, the `onChange` property is redundant and unnecessary—it provides an opportunity to perform some other actions when the `item` property—that is, the bound `fname` property—changes, so the cell will have already been updated when it executes.)

So, if you now change the name of a `Person` instance, what happens to the cell for that `Person` in the "Name" column? Nothing.

Why?

Firstly, as @James_D points out, you have not established a relationship between the `name` of a `Person` instance, and the value of the `ObjectProperty` instance originally associated with it. That is, all you've done is change a `String` value. For the GUI to be updated, the value of that `ObjectProperty` needs to change too.

Adding to your problem is the fact that there is no relationship from the `Person` to its associated `PersonView`. So, when the `Person` `name` field is changed, there's no way for the `Person` to person to notify its `PersonView`. Worse, by making `PersonView` an `implicit` class, you're suggesting that `PersonView` instances themselves are unimportant and transient, existing temporarily solely to decorate some `Person` instance with an additional set of methods and/or properties.

So, how can we change things so that they work as you might expect? There are two basic approaches, and your choice will depend upon how much control you can exert on the `Person` class. The key in both cases is to ensure that the `StringProperty` (a better option than an `ObjectProperty`, incidentally) containing the name of the `Person` changes whenever the `name` of the `Person` is changed...

Firstly, the simplest method is to do away with `PersonView` class altogether. Clearly, you'll need to be able to edit `Person` to do this; if you cannot, you'll have to try the second approach. `Person` should be modified to add an `fname` property field, with `name` being converted to a function that reports the current value of `fname`:

```scala
// initName is the initial name of the Person, and may be changed later...
class Person(initName: String, /*Whatever other arguments you require*/) {

  // String property storing this Person's name. Name is initialized to initName.
  val fname = new StringProperty(this, "fname", initName)

  // Report the current name of this Person.
  def name = fname.value

  // This function is not necessary, since we could change the value through fname directly
  // but it does look better...
  def name_=(newName: String): Unit = fname.value = newName
}
```

In this case, your table initialization now looks like this:

```scala
val tableLines = ObservableBuffer(persView) // Of Person, not PersonView!
val personTable = new TableView[Person](tableLines) {
  columns ++= List(
    new TableColumn[Person, String] {
      text = "Name"
      cellValueFactory = _.value.fname
      // No need for a cellFactory - default works fine.
    }
  )
}
```

Now, you can change the name of a `Person` like this:

```scala
val someone = new Person("Bob"/*, etc...*/)
someone.name = "Fred"
```

And all is good. The `fname` property, the `name` field *and* the value of the corresponding cell in the GUI table, will now all have the same value.

The second approach is required if you cannot modify the definition of the `Person` type. Here, we use `PersonView` to change the names of `Person` instances, and hope that no-one changes `Person` names outside of our control. (That is, if some other code modifies the name of a `Person` instance without going through `PersonView`, then we'll know nothing about it, and the GUI will not be updated accordingly.)

`PersonView`, in this case, *must not* be an `implicit` class. We want to retain a `PersonView` instance and use it to interact with an associated `Person` instance. `PersonView` now looks like this:

```scala
class PersonView(p: Person) {

  // String property initialized to the name of the associated person.
  val fname = new StringProperty(this, "fname", p.name)

  // Change the name of the person. Note that we MUST also change the name of the
  // associated person instance.
  def name_=(newName: String): Unit = {

    // Change the name of the Person instance. Verify it has the value we think it has.
    assert(p.name == fname.value)
    p.name = newName // Might be p.setName(newName), etc. in your case

    // Change the name of our property.
    fname.value = newName
  }
}
```

Now, say you have a list of `Person` instances, you'll need to map them to `PersonView` instances, and use those latter instances subsequently.

Your GUI code now looks like this:

```scala
val tableLines = ObservableBuffer(persView)
val personTable = new TableView[PersonView](tableLines) {
  columns ++= List(
    new TableColumn[PersonView, String] {
      text = "Name"
      cellValueFactory = _.value.fname
      // No need for a cellFactory - default works fine.
    }
  )
}
```

Changing the names of people is now a little more complex, because we need to be able to find the right `PersonView` instance, but it would look like this:

```scala
val someone = new Person("Bob"/*, etc...*/)
val someoneView = new PersonView(someone)
someoneView.name = "Fred"
```

And all is good once again. The `PersonView.fname` property, the `Person.name` field *and* the value of the corresponding cell in the GUI table (once `someoneView` is added to the `tableLines` observable), will now all have the same value.

However, the following line just changes the name of a `Person` instance. The `PersonView` and GUI do *not* get updated:

```scala
someone.name = "Eric"
```